# How do you link together two struct-type variables together in c#?

Tags: c#, struct

My question is simple; how can I link together two structs so that modifying one changes the other in c#? Is this even possible due to the nature of structs?

In code, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```cs
Vector2 a = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.7f);
Vector2 b = a; // This line needs changing
b.X = 1.0f;
Debug.WriteLine(a.X); // should print 1.0f, but actually prints 0.5f.
```

For context, I'm making a game in MonoGame and need to link sprite positions together, which naturally use the built-in datatype "Vector2", which is a struct.

Comment: You could make one a `ref` of the other

Comment: C# `structs` are value types, so this won't work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct

Comment: Alternatively, instead of value type such as struct, use reference type such as class (with public set accessor if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Structures are value type, so they are copy-by-value. You can use references, however, which are handy if you want to pass a structure around by reference to parameters, or as return values from class members.

[For example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgZgAIMiBhIgbzyNpPXSprpYDcBDMI9ogXiKgBTAO5EAauwA2EQQBUIAB0mCAPKkwAGGEQCWUYAD4AFACIAZgHsLJ7ZgCUAbmYtaYQWaIcuAIz5E3HuxOuC50zi7eAHQAksCCALaM/OjBobTqAJxG7I7hAL54eUA===):

```cs
var a = new ValueTuple<string, int>("foo", 1);
ref var b = ref a;
        
b.Item2 = 2;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns for more information.

Comment: This is a good answer for my question as it is currently phrased (replacing `Vector2 b = a` with `ref var b = ref a` makes the code print 1), though I vaguely mentioned that I'm using fields to store the data, so ref locals won't work in my case. There are other questions that deal with people asking for ref fields though, so I'll accept the answer as is.

Comment: @ZachK you should edit your question to match answer you've accepted - as question currently stands this can't be an answer to " to link sprite positions together".

Comment: Fair enough, though I don't think I should edit my question as is.